# How to protect codeigniter application source file

Tags: php, codeigniter

### What I Am Trying

I am building a Codeigniter application for a client.I need to upload the codeigniter application in the client server. Therefore I need to encrypt or protect my source files.

### What I Require

What should I do to protect or encrypt my Codeigniter source file or Project.

Comment: A better solution, imho, would be selling your product with a proper licence that forbids modifications / changes of the source code. Also, keep in mind CI's licence: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/license.html it's no clear from there if you're allowed or not, you should drop a note to Ellis Lab and ask

Answer (score 1):

Well that would take away the whole point of open source now would it.
You will have to encrypt/obfuscate your source by using ionCube or Zend encoders.
However, I am not sure if the app will work after encoding since you are using a framework.
ionCube says that they work with codeigniter but I don't have any experience for it.

I haven't used Zend before.
Even though you encrypt them I have seen posts where they claim to be able to get the normal clean code. I don't know how much of this is true.

But if you need to protect the source code ionCube or Zend encoders say that they can.
http://www.ioncube.com/ OR http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/

Answer (score 0):

i also needed this type of feature and all users suggest [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/) and [ZendGuard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/) but this software is paid versions. so research on this feature i get a such a perfect tool and it's allow to make only single PHP file encoding as i want i use this.

after implement this encoded code in my project no affect to code and works perfectly and it is [Byterun](http://www.byterun.com/free-php-encoder.php).

Comment: Note that Zend Guard has been discontinued since last year (http://blog.zend.com/2016/10/10/zend-guard-and-php-7/). Tools such as Byterun are fine for basic code hiding, though easily undone with a tool such as https://github.com/jacobsoo/Decoder-ByteRun as the source is restored at runtime.  High end solutions are paid because they are provided by real companies where there can be significant costs merely to exist, there are ongoing costs of development, there are people employed to provide support, etc. It's horses for courses. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in ionCube. The problem is when CodeIgniter code is obfusacate and encrypted, the calling area of that function/class/variable does not recognize newly created function/class/variable name and generates error.

ionCube knows the pitfalls and offers a way to exclude such files that are being called outside that file, but thats what MVC do. Not an elegant solution by ionCube.

https://blog.ioncube.com/2014/10/16/common-obfuscation-pitfalls/

I did not check ZendGuard, but my guts feelings says, the same problem will appear if we use any code encryption tool. The point is, we made a file, class, method, variable encrypt and obfuscate (encrypt / obfuscate), after the process, it will produce new name for class, method, variable. Now, another model, controller, method is calling the same variable/method, and then it will not recognized and an error will be thrown. I am not 100% sure in case of ZendGuard or other tools but checked the ionCube.

Comment: These are not issues with the tools. 1) Obfuscation renames entities, so using their original names in a context unaware of the changes should not work. Using original names within protected code, even `$fn()` where `$fn` is a variable with the name of a function, should work though. Note that enabling obfuscation is not essential for code protection. 2) Some systems rely on reading sourcecode to obtain information, so cannot work if files are protected. This is poor design, but once understood, should not present a barrier to protecting files. 3) Zend Guard was discontinued a few years ago.